# Select data depend with IF ELSE condition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have a query as below :

```
SELECT R.*
FROM 
(
    WITH TABLE_X AS
    (
        SELECT A,B,C FROM Y
    )

    --PSEUDO CODE
     IF (COUNT(TABLE_X.*) > 0)
        THEN SELECT CONCAT(A ,B, C) FROM TABLE_X
     ELSE 'No Data'
     END
) R
```

In this case, If TABLE_X have data, the selection will return A,B,C. In others way, this will return something else like 'No data'.

Please help me clarify and suggest some soluiton on it.
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Just as a starting point, consider that a query can return a fixed number of columns. What do you need this query for? Is some kind of report, a simple check query, do you need data to be returned in some variable? Please try to be more detailed.

Comment: This query will reuturn fixed number of columns.
This query used for report. It return data without variable.

Answer (score 0):

If there is at most one row in `TABLE_X`, then you can use aggregation:

```
WITH TABLE_X AS (
      SELECT A, B, C FROM Y
    )
SELECT (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 0 THEN 'No Data'
             ELSE MAX(A || B || C)
        END) as col
FROM TABLE_X;
```

Alternatively, use `UNION ALL`:

```
WITH TABLE_X AS (
      SELECT A, B, C FROM Y
    )
SELECT A || B || C as col
FROM TABLE_X
UNION ALL
SELECT 'No Data'
FROM Dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE_X);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking too you query  i  think you simply need

```
 select  nvl( A||B,||C , 'No data') 
 from y
```